# Trying to display advanced custom fields information only yields empty results

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to display a food menu created via Advanced Custom Fields Pro, however when I try to display the information from the fields I get nowhere despite doing it a lot of times in the past. I've been going over the code a bunch of times but I can't find what's wrong with it..

**My structure of the fields look like this:**

[image: structure of fields]

The top image is what it looks like when creating the information. The other two is the name of the fields, which are `days` and the sub field is called `days_day`, I got 5 sub fields, one for each day of the week.

**Then I try to display this info via this script:**

```
<ul id="food-menu-content" class="clearfix no-bullet-list">

<?php
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'meny'
  );

  $menu_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<?php if ( $menu_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $menu_query->have_posts() ) : $menu_query->the_post(); ?>

  <?php if ( have_rows('days') ) : while ( have_rows('days') ) : the_row(); ?>

    <?php if ( have_rows('days_day' ) ) : while ( have_rows( 'days_day' ) ) : the_row(); ?>

      <li>
        <h3><?php the_sub_field('days_day'); ?></h3>
      </li>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?> <!-- have_rows('days_day') -->

  <?php endwhile; endif; ?> <!-- have_rows('days') -->

<?php endwhile; endif; ?> <!-- $menu_query -->

</ul>
```

The fields are connected to a custom post type called "meny" which I run my own `WP_Query` on and then I try and access the information from the fields during the current iteration.

Problem with this script is that I only get one `li` from the loop and it's completely empty of information. When really I should get 5 since I have 5 sub fields (`days_day`).

What is wrong here?

Comment: I guess the name of the subfield of `days_day` should be something else (not `days_day` again), maybe that's the reason you get an empty value. That said, judging by [this example](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/working-with-nested-repeaters/#template) of nested repeater fields, the loops structure seems ok.